# Copy and Paste Multiple Sheets to One Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, count, copy-paste

I have multiple worksheets (for this example say Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) with same number of columns, but different row counts (changes constantly).
I want to consolidate all of these on one sheet.

The headings on the Consolidation sheet have been pre-set and so I am starting to paste into Row 2 of that sheet.

Sheet1 = 5000 rows (inc header row) - there are no blank rows at bottom

Sheet2 = 300 rows (inc header row) -  ditto

Sheet3 = 1200 rows (inc header row) - ditto

Consolidation = 1 row (header row only) - ditto

When I paste Sheet1 (the first sheet) into Consolidation, it does start in Row 2 but it also pastes blank rows to fill the entire worksheet to 1,048,576 rows (limit of sheet).

How do I find the first blank row, and then paste Sheet2 data (from Row 2) onto the bottom, and continue with similar for next sheet.

```vb
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:CF" & Rows.Count).Copy
Sheets("Consolidate").Activate
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specifying the last row to do the copy paste. Try something like that is, and try to avoid using select.

```
Sub CheckDuplicateAcrossWorkbook()
Dim pullWs As Worksheet, dropWS As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

Set pullWs = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dropWS = Sheets("Consolidate")

'make sure no rows are hidden)
lastRow = pullWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

pullWs.Range("A2:CF" & lastRow).Copy
dropWS.Range("A2").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you!  I was starting to pull my hair out! - that first part now works perfectly.  Obviously not got my tongue on the right side of my mouth.  :P          In regards to Sheet2 and Sheet3 data, where I don't know what row to paste for dropWS, do you have a suggestion on how to modify to find the next available/blank row?  (then presumably it's just a case of inserting the value as a variable?)

Comment: Ah, answered own question:  I need to do an additional DIM LastRowConsolidated to identify that row on that sheet (+ 1), and then update the rest for each successive sheet to add the data.   Thank you for your help, and pointing me in the right direction to complete the coding.  Cheers.

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks for accepting.